# Loading a txt file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a text file that is stored on my local machine to a div when a button is clicked

My HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Help</title>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="magic">Click me</button>

<div class="here"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#magic").click(function(){
        $(".here").load("helloworld.txt");
    });

});
```

My text file

helloworld.txt which says hello world!!!!

The error I am getting in the inspector is :

jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/justin/Code/test/helloworld.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You should use a web-server for that

Comment: You can't do ajax unless page is opened from a server and not from `file/open`. Install a localhost server

Comment: @charlietfl ajax is possible at `file:` protocol.

Comment: @guest271314 sure if you change browser security settings but in general that's not a good idea and it is so easy to set up a server

Comment: @charlietfl _"You can't do ajax unless page is opened from a server and not from `file/open`"_ is not accurate as to "can't". The flag is used to test functionality locally at chromium, chrome. _"By default, file:// URIs cannot read other file:// URIs. This is an override for developers who need the old behavior for testing."_

Comment: You can't do that . because browser doesn't have access to any part of Client .unless you uploaded this file on server and read it by C# or any other language like that and take it by Ajax call

Comment: Caddyserver.com provides a really easy way to setup a webserver

Comment: @TobyAllen `php` has a builtin server designed to be used locally. Though OP is not asking how to set up a server; but rather, how to use `XMLHttpRequest` to get a file from local filesystem at `file:` protocol, specifically at chromium, chrome browsers.